# Is there a nice GUI for CVS under Linux?

Tags: gui, comparison, cvs

I'm wondering if there is a nice modern GUI for CVS under Linux, something that will make files comparison visual and easy ...

Comment: What tools have you found so far?  How do they not measure up to what you want?  (You did search your favorite Linux distro's packaging system, right?)  Also try searching for "visual diff" tools.  And *why CVS?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try either [Cervisia](http://www.kde.org/applications/development/cervisia/) or [CrossVC](http://www.crossvc.com/).

Comment: Cervisia is very good indeed, it is exactly what i was looking for !!

Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! :) Please upvote the answer(s) you believe are useful and then choose the most useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Cervisia](https://www.kde.org/applications/development/cervisia/) is a user friendly version control system front-end.

https://www.kde.org/applications/development/cervisia/

Comment: Cervisia is very good indeed, it is exactly what i was looking for !!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is for instance [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/):

> Meld is a GNOME 2 visual diff and
>   merge tool. It integrates especially
>   well with CVS. The diff viewer lets
>   you edit files in place (diffs update
>   dynamically), and a middle column
>   shows detailed changes and allows
>   merges. The margins show location of
>   changes for easy navigation, and it
>   also features a tabbed interface that
>   allows you to open many diffs at once.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has a very nice cvs package with [PCL-CVS](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cvs/pcl-cvs_toc.html) which offers pretty much anything one could want.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's integrated CVS browser is spot-on, and it is cross-platform:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-cvs/